# Why doesn't my JS function work with my button?

Tags: javascript

- Trying to make my own play button
- Audio loads and plays fine with the HTML Audio Tag
- Error console says "Fails to load resource https://open.scdn.co/static/embed.2019-03-05_152e14cd.js.map"
- song.play(); typed into JS console works fine
- Button does not activate function!

HTML

```
                <audio id="song" controls> <source src="song.mp3"></source>
                </audio>
                <button class="controls" id="play">Play</button>
```

JavaScript

```
            var play = document.getElementById("song");
            song.addEventListener ("click", buttonActions);
            function buttonActions(event){
                song.play();
            }
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript code in relation to the HTML?

Comment: I don't see `song` being defined anywhere

Comment: @IsaacVidrine: IDs become global variables.

Comment: @FelixKling okay, but `song` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine: `<audio id="song" controls>`

Comment: No, that is not a definition of the variable `song`. That is giving an id to a DOM element. Giving an element an id does not mean it is available as a property in javascript. If it were, what would be the point of `document.getElementById`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine: I just said *" IDs become global variables."*. But maybe this is better: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/218196). I can also offer this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/tzvurLy8/

Comment: @FelixKling Wow, honestly had no clue that existed, but for good reasons I see why I never knew it was a thing, cause no one should really ever use it.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine: That's correct :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attaching the event handler to the `<audio>` element, instead of the `<button>` element.

Instead of:

```
var play = document.getElementById("song");
song.addEventListener ("click", buttonActions);    
function buttonActions(event){
    song.play();
}
```

It should be:

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
play.addEventListener ("click", buttonActions);    
function buttonActions(event){
    var song = document.getElementById("song");
    song.play();
}
```